# How can I find out if an ordered item in Magento was on stock in a php script?

Tags: php, magento

I need to find out for an automated fulfillment/report php-script if the ordered item was on stock when it was bought or not.

I initially thought of using the Item Staus which has a "Backordered Status", but this is overwritten when the invoice is created, which is in our case always directly the case because our payment methods are configured like that.

I looked at the sales_flat_order_item table and the only solution that comes to my mind is if I can use the qty_backordered field to check if the item was initially backordered or not but I'm not sure if this is a reliable method.

How would you do that in a secure way?

Comment: Yes you can do this. Please edit your question and tell us what you’ve already tried.

Answer (score 0):

create a new file and use this file in your magento root

Magento get all the simple products which have greater than 0 quantity and are still Out of Stock in inventory.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
set_time_limit(0);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->joinField('qty',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'qty',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '{{table}}.is_in_stock=0',
             'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));

echo "<h2>Simple Products with >0 quantity and Out of Stock</h2>";
foreach($productCollection as $product) { //print_r($product->getData());exit;
if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple')
    echo $product->getName() . " | " . $product->getSku() . "<br>";
}
echo 'Done';
?>
```

Comment: sorry, but that is not an answer to my question! I'm asking explicitly for an ordered item, which means I need to know for an order if the item that was purchased was on stock at the time of the purchase or not and not if a product is generally on stock or not.

Comment: did you try anything?